# android app using java as language using intelliJ IDE

Tags: java, android, android-layout, intellij-idea

For my program ITax,
I have several layouts aside from main.xml. 
I have 3 buttons in the main.xml and one

1. btn_info - opens basicinfo.xml when clicked
2. btn_tutorial - opens tutorial.xml when clicked
3. btn_calc - opens calculator.xml when clicked

My code for these buttons in the Main.java is (this works!):

```
package com.example.ITax;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
         btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tutorial);
         btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calc);

          btn1.setOnClickListener(i);
          btn2.setOnClickListener(i);
          btn3.setOnClickListener(i);


public View.OnClickListener i = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v == btn1)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.basic_info);
            }

            else if (v == btn2)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
            }

            else if (v == btn3)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.calcu);
            }


        }
    } ;
```

BUT.. when I include a button from calcu.xml for example:

1. btn_back_from_calcu - go backs to main.xml when clicked

This is my new code that doesn't work (whenever i run my app in the emulator, it says that "Unfortunately, ITax stopped."

```
package com.example.ITax;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

         btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_info);
         btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tutorial);
         btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_calc);
         btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back_from_calcu);

          btn1.setOnClickListener(i);
          btn2.setOnClickListener(i);
          btn3.setOnClickListener(i);
          btn4.setOnClickListener(i);
}
}

public View.OnClickListener i = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (v == btn1)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.basic_info);
            }

            else if (v == btn2)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
            }

            else if (v == btn3)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.calcu);
            }

             else if (v == btn4)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
        }
    } ;
```

WHAT SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM?! :'((

Comment: What do you mean by "stops the program"? Is there an exception in the logcat trace?

Comment: @GrahamBorland i've updated my question so that everyone can understand my problem more clearly. hope that helps!